# Allow ssh protocol through win 10 firewall

Tags: ssh, firewall, openssh, windows-firewall

I have a workstation with Win 10 on which I installed OpenSSH server. If I try to connect to it (from another machine with Win 10 using ssh in a command prompt) I see it gives the following error:

> ssh: connect to host Test3 port 22: Connection timed out

On wireshark Syn packets are sent but no answer is received back.
If I dissable Windows firewall on destination then connection is established.

I want to leave the firewall enabled and disable only ssh port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found on microsoft site a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule) which allow to do it using graphical interface.
I solved my problem performing the following steps as administrator:

- Open the Group Policy Management Console / File/ Add snap-in / Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security(or Windows Settings/ Windows Defender Firewall / Advanced settings).
- Inbound Rules / Actions / New rule
- Rule Type / Port / Next
- TCP / Specific port: 22 / Next
- Allow the connection / Next / Next
- Name / Open ssh port 22 / Finish

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use netsh.exe.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open SSH Port 22" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=22 remoteip=any
```

You can also change remoteip to a specific host:

```
remoteip=any|localsubnet|dns|dhcp|wins|defaultgateway|<IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>
```

Comment: I also found on microsoft site a link which allow to do it using graphical interface: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule